# Visual Format String Grammar in auto layout

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

I want to learn auto layout and see this [official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html).In Visual Format String Grammar chapter,I don't understand Replacement rule.What does "?" and "*" means?

Comment: Those are regular expression rules.  * means 0 or more, and ? means 0 or 1.  It is not needed for using the grammar, it is just showing how to format a VFL string.

Comment: Agreed, that grammar is not really to the point. Just see some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the grammar is given in a sort of [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) form, which is used in computer science to describe [context-free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).

Specifically,

- `?` expresses optionality, meaning 0 or 1 repetitions
- `*` expresses 0 or more repetitions
- `|` expresses an alternative

For instance

```
(<predicate>(,<predicate>)*)
```

means a `<predicate>`, followed by an arbitrary number of `,<predicate>`, possibly 0.

And

```
[<viewName>(<predicateListWithParens>)?]
```

means either `[<viewName><predicateListWithParens>]` or just `[<viewName>]`

Finally

```
H|V
```

means either `H` or `V`.